# Changing autocommit before query and resetting it after

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

I am relatively new to MySQL. I just 'discovered' transactions.
I knew they existed but never looked into them.
What I want to know:

I work in PHP and use INNODB as database engine.

*Can I just set `autocommit = 0;` before a sending a query and setting it to 1 after the query?*

The reason I ask this because I made quite a big project already and don't feel the need to 'convert' the entire thing to transactions. It feels like if someone would submit something and autocommit would be set to 0 and someone else would send a non-transaction query the second one wouldn't 'fire' as it's not a transaction.

If I want to use transactions, do I need to apply it to the entire project? Or is it session only or some other workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to disable `autocommit` when you want to wrap multiple statements into a single transaction, just use mysqli's [mysqli_begin_transaction()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) and [mysqli_commit()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) functions / methods to start / commit transactions (I'll let you figure out how to roll a transaction back).

If you explicitly start a transaction, then it disables the [autocommit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html) for the duration of the transaction:

> A session that has autocommit enabled can perform a multiple-statement transaction by starting it with an explicit START TRANSACTION or BEGIN statement and ending it with a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement.

Pls note that even with `autocommit` enabled innodb uses transactions for all data modification statements. All this setting means that every data modification statement is wrapped into a single-statement transaction without you specifying a transaction.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I did not know about these functions. Also, I wasn't paying attention with the tags, I'll be more carefull next time! :)